# PHP Regex match, match all lines that begin with number followed by period

Tags: php, regex, simple-html-dom

I used `simple_html_dom`, to parse some HTML and have the following HTML Table that in an array called `$pre`

Now, how can I use PHP regex to get only the lines that match the result below?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre>1.   APEAL/890/2010     HUSSAIN ISMAIL SATWILKAR        SHRI C.K. PENDSE</pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre>     [Criminal]                                         MS.ROHINI DANDEKAR ADV.AP</pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre>                        V/S THE STATE OF MAHARASH       PTD AS PER CTS ORD 7/9/17</pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre>                        TRA                             P.P.FOR  P. P</pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre></pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre>        REMARK : (By Accused against Conviction) Note: (1) Matter is Ready for final</pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre>                 hearing. (2) Accd. is in jail. (3) R & P with PB received. (4)</pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre>                 Muddemal article are to be called for. (5) Report received from</pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre>                 Nashik Central Prison stated therein that "Orig. accd. death dated</pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre>                 20/11/2015 (Report kept at flag "A") . ....... Court (DB) for final</pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre>                 hearing.</pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre></pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre></pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre></pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre>2.   APEAL/966/2011     ABDUL MALIK SHAIKH              SHRI S. R. MITHARE</pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre>     [Criminal]</pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre>                        V/S THE STATE OF MAHARASH</pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre>                        TRA</pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre></pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre>        REMARK : (By Accused Against Conviction) Note:- (1) Matter is ready for</pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre>                 Final Hearing. (2) Original Accused is in Jail. (3) R & P received</pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre>                 with PaperBooks. (4) Muddemal Articles are to be called for. (5)</pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre>                 Report received from Kolhapur central Prison stated therein that</pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre>                 "Orig. Accused expired on 19/04/2015 (Report kept at flag "A")</pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre>                 - Court D.B. for Final Hearing.</pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre></pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre></pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre></pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre>3.   APEAL/486/2012     AJAY SITARAM BHARATI            MISS. TANU KHATTRI</pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre>     [Criminal]</pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Result after using Regex:**

```
<pre>1.   APEAL/890/2010     HUSSAIN ISMAIL SATWILKAR        SHRI C.K. PENDSE</pre>
<pre>2.   APEAL/966/2011     ABDUL MALIK SHAIKH              SHRI S. R. MITHARE</pre>
<pre>3.   APEAL/486/2012     AJAY SITARAM BHARATI            MISS. TANU KHATTRI</pre>
```

Using this code: `preg_match('^\<pre\>\d2*\./gm', $pre[$i])` returns:
`preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found`

This looks like the correct regex to use, this is from regex101:

```
^ asserts position at start of the string
\< matches the character < literally (case sensitive)
pre matches the characters pre literally (case sensitive)
\> matches the character > literally (case sensitive)
\d matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
    2* matches the character 2 literally (case sensitive)
    * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)

Global pattern flags
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
```

Comment: In php you have to add delimiters to your pattern, you miss the `/` delimiter before the `^`

EDIT: Plus there is no modifier `g` for preg_match. Instead, you have to use the preg_match_all function.

Comment: You have a DOM parser running over the page. Why not querying `pre` elements directly from it?

Comment: @revo, `$pre` is an array of `<pre>` elements from the `simple_html_dom` parser.

Comment: What I see is a table not an array of `pre` elements.

Comment: well, it's pretty obvious that you don't know what `simple_html_dom` parser does, then.

Comment: If I didn't know, I wouldn't question your XY problem. You'd better talk about the problem not the solution.

Comment: I didn't have an XY problem because I already knew how to get the `<pre>` elements. Answer already selected, move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The php [`preg_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) functions require a delimiter - a symbol that is not used within the pattern.

Also, your pattern won't match correctly. The reason for this is that `^` matches the very start of the line. And the `pre` tag doesn't start for a few tabs.

This regex will match any `pre` tag that is on the same line, that starts with at least one number (for example, 1, 16, 256, etc) and a period.

```
preg_match('#(<pre>\d+\..*</pre>)#', $pre[$1], $matches);
vaR_dump($matches);
```

In this example, I've used `#` as the delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need:

```
#<pre>(?<line>\d+\..+)<\/pre>#
```

Obviously you know what pre is. The brackets denote a capture group, which I have named 'line', by putting `?<line>` in the brackets.

Then it looks for a number `\d+\`, a literal dot `\.`, anything `.+` followed by the closing tag.

```
$regex = '#<pre>(?<line>\d+\..+)<\/pre>#';

preg_match_all($regex, $html, $matches);

foreach($matches['line'] as $line) {
    echo $line ."\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1. APEAL/890/2010 HUSSAIN ISMAIL SATWILKAR SHRI C.K. PENDSE 
2. APEAL/966/2011 ABDUL MALIK SHAIKH SHRI S. R. MITHARE
```

Here it is in action: https://regex101.com/r/6U8S9C/1

And again running in php: https://3v4l.org/QoVsY